# How to use Google fonts in email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I'm working on email templates front end design, currently having problem in using google fonts, how can I embed or use google font in my email templates.

I've added the google font this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
font-family:'Oswald';
</style>
```

Please guide me in the correct way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the which mail platform the receiver receives the email.  For example outlook is a pain.

I use this;

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local("Open Sans Regular"), local("OpenSans-Regular"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format("woff2");
unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215; }
```

Comment: Lets assume it's for Gmail client, and I want to use google Oswald font family, so where do I add this code, in template header ?

Comment: Yes, put it into the header for your template with all of your other CSS.  Then you can use the font-family: style wherever you need the font.  You could also have a look at this link for outlook work arounds https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/custom-font-stacks-in-outlook/